# GetChildHtml() issue - Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="pricetool/result" name="update.info.block"  as="update.info.block"  template="pricetool/pricetool.phtml" />
</refrence>
```

I have created this code in **xml** and I want to call it in my **phtml** file using `$this->getChildHtml()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your block is not a child, if you are sure of your block type, you can update it like this:

```
<your_layout_handle>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="pricetool/result" name="update.info.block"  as="inf.block"  template="pricetool/pricetool.phtml" />
    </refrence>
</your_layout_handle>
```

Then you call it in your phtml like this:

```
 <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('update.info.block'); ?>
```

**UPDATE:**
When can you call you block as a child ?

```
<your_layout_handle>
   <reference name="root">
       <block type="pricetool/result" name="update.info.block"  as="inf.block"  template="pricetool/pricetool.phtml">
            <block type="pricetool/result" name="block.two" as="two"  template="path.phtml"/> //this one is a child
       </block>
   </refrence>
</your_layout_handle>
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('two'); ?>
```

Comment: oh how we know that our block is child or not

Comment: Look my update please.

Answer (score 0):

First of you have check , your **block type** and **template** is working fine using Below code. to check your codeing is working or not .after testing you will remove form PHTML.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('pricetool/result')->setTemplate('pricetool/pricetool.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

If you getting a result then please remove for PHTML and call into using XML and getChildHtml() Function like below .

You can call useing **as="TEXT"** so.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('update.info.block'); ?>
```

May be it will work.

Comment: it woking but i want to call by getchildhtm current i define it xml and it show on page without calling

Comment: @uber there is no way to set without using getChildHtml

Comment: you not getting my point

Comment: Give me Ex so will got .

Answer (score 0):

Well you have placed your block inside

```
<reference name="content">
</reference>
```

If you go to inside page.xml you can see the below.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
    <label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>
```

So the block type of `content` block is `core/text_list`. Any block with blocktype `core/text_list` in magento is a special (structural) block. And all blocks inside structural blocks will be rendered by default. You don't have to use `getChildHtml()` for that. If you want to use `getChildHtml()` then place that block inside some other block type or don't place that block directly inside `content` block.

Comment: goood really thanx and informative for me